# Show by induction $|a_1-a_2+a_3-\ldots \pm a_n| \leq |a_1|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, induction

The assumptions are that $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence with $(a_n) \to 0 $, that is all terms are nonnegative. It is easy to see that the subtracted terms are always at least as great as the added ones because of the decreasing assumption but can this be formalised with an induction argument? Thank you.

Comment: Decreasing sequence and all terms non-negative do not necessarily mean the limit is zero

Comment: By the given info you don't need absolute value on the right side in the inequality...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, indeed.

Comment: In fact, I don't think you need the abs. value in the left side, either...

Comment: @DonAntonio Nope. It's all nonnegative numbers. This is part of the proof of the alternating series test by the way.

Comment: I thought so, @JohnK ...;)

Comment: @peterwhy You are right. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement is trivially true for $n=1$, and can be checked to be true for $n=2$.

Now, assume the statement is true for some $n=k$ and $n=k+1$. Consider the statement for $n=k+2$.

If $n=k+2$ is odd, the left hand side becomes
$$LHS = a_1-a_2 + a_3-\cdots+a_k-a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}\le a_1-(a_{k+1}-a_{k+2})\le a_1$$
using the assumption from $n=k$.

And if $n=k+2$ is even, then the left hand side becomes

$$LHS = a_1-a_2 + a_3-\cdots-a_k+a_{k+1}-a_{k+2} \le a_1-a_{k+2} \le a_1$$

using the assumption from $n=k+1$.

---

This rely on the fact that the sum on the left hand side inside absolute sign is always non-negative, and can be proved similarly by induction:

$$a_1-a_2+a_3-\cdots-(-1)^na_n \ge 0$$

Comment: Is it correct to use different assumptions of $n$ for each case?

Comment: I assumed $S(k)$ and $S(k+1)$ to prove $S(k+2)$, that's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Induction on $\;n\;$

$$a_1\le a_1 . \text{Suppose now for $\;n\;$ and we shall prove for $\;n+1\;$}:$$

Suppose first $\;n+1\;$ is even

$$a_1-a_2+\ldots+a_n-a_{n+1}=\left(a_1-a_2+\ldots+a_n\right)-a_{n+1}\le a_1-a_{n+1}\le a_1$$

since $\;a_{n+1}\ge 0\;$.

Do now the other case.

Comment: How do you simplify the other case, given that what we get is $$(a_1-a_2+\ldots-a_n)+a_{n+1} \leq a_1+a_{n+1}$$